# simultaneous fitting python parameter sharing

Tags: python, curve-fitting, least-squares, data-fitting

I have six datasets, I wish to fit all six datasets simultaneously, with two parameters common between the six datasets and one to be fit seperately.

I'm planning to fit a simple ax**2+bx+c polynomial to the datasets, where a and b is shared between the six datasets and the offset, c, is not shared between the six.

Therefore I'm fitting a common slope between the datasets but with a variable offset.

I'm fully competent in fitting them individually, however as the slopes are similar between each dataset, the error on the offset, c, would be greatly improved using simultaneous fitting.

I typically fit using the scipy.optmize.curve_fit.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x,a,b,c):
    return (a*(x**2)+b*x+c)
def fit(x,y,yerr):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y,p0=[-0.6,5,-12],sigma=yerr)
    chi=np.sum( ((func(x, *popt) - y) / yerr)**2)
    redchi=(chi-1)/len(y)
    return popt,pcov,redchi,len(y)
```

I'm handling 6 sets of: x,xerr,y,yerr
len(x) and len(y) is different for each set.

I understand I have to concatenate the datasets and fit them this way.

If anyone can offer any advice or help, I'm sure it would be beneficial for both me and the community.

Comment: Is it a Python problem or a mathematical problem?

Comment: Are you saying that you will have six values of `c` (say `c_1`... `c_6`) and one value for each of `a` and `b`, such that the model for dataset_i will be `a*x**2 + b*x + c_i`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yes, The a and b are the same fitted value across all 6 datasets, and the there will be 6 fitted values of c.

Comment: @Laurent LAPORTE, it's mainly a python problem currently. Is there a way to fit with shared parameters? And can you put datasets in a matrix to fit them simultaneously?

Comment: I don't know how to do this with `scipy.curve_fit`, but I could write up a simple two-chromosome genetic algorithm to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions, I seem to have found a way to fit them simultaneously with a,b and c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 as the parameters, where a and b are shared.

Below is the code I used in the end:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x=[vt,bt,ut,w1t,m2t,w2t]
y=[vmag,bmag,umag,w1mag,m2mag,w2mag]
xerr=[vterr,uterr,bterr,w1terr,m2terr,w2terr]
yerr=[vmagerr,umagerr,bmagerr,w1magerr,m2magerr,w2magerr]

def poly(x_, a, b, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6):
    #all this is just to split x_data into the original parts of x
    l= len(x[0])
    l1= len(x[1])
    l2= len(x[2])
    l3= len(x[3])
    l4= len(x[4])
    l5= len(x[5])
    s=l+l1
    s1=l2+s
    s2=l3+s1
    s3=l4+s2
    s4=l5+s3


    a= np.hstack([
a*x_[:l]**2 + b*x_[:l] +c1,
a*x_[l:(s)]**2 + b*x_[l:(s)] +c2,
a*x_[(s):(s1)]**2 + b*x_[(s):(s1)] +c3,
a*x_[(s1):(s2)]**2 + b*x_[(s1):(s2)] +c4,
a*x_[(s2):(s3)]**2 + b*x_[(s2):(s3)] +c5,
a*x_[(s3):(s4)]**2 + b*x_[(s3):(s4)] +c6
])       
    print a
    return a 
x_data = np.hstack([x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5]])
y_data = np.hstack([y[0],y[1],y[2],y[3],y[4],y[5]])

(a, b, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6), _ = curve_fit(poly, x_data, y_data)
```

Apologies if this is awful coding! I'm very rough with my approach! However, it certainly does the job well!

Below is my resulting fit.

[Fitted results from simultaneous fitting with shared parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShrfK.png)

Answer (score 4):

Because I had similar fitting problems, I made [`symfit`](http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitting_types.html#global-fitting) to deal with this kind of scenario. So I'm sorry for shamelessly suggesting my own package but I think it would be very helpful for you. It wraps curve fit but provides a symbolic interface to make things easier.

Your problem could be solved like this:

```
from symfit import variables, parameters, Fit

xs = variables('x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6')
ys = variables('y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5, y_6')

a, b = parameters('a, b')
cs = parameters(', '.join('c_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 6)))

model_dict = {
    y: a * x**2 + b * x + c
        for x, y, c in zip(xs, ys, cs)
}

fit = Fit(model_dict, x_1=x1_data, x_2=x2_data, ..., y_1=y1_data, ..., sigma_y_1=y1_err, sigma_y_2=y2_err, ...)
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(fit_result)
```

Check out the docs for more:
http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitting_types.html#global-fitting

p.s. to give initial guesses to your parameters, each `Parameter` object comes with a `.value` attribute which holds the initial guess. So for example, `a.value = -0.6`.

**Edit:**
Previously some additional workaround was needed, which explains some of the discussion below. However, I have now released a new `symfit` version in which the above code runs as expected.

Comment: I've checked your python package, and it seems really neat! I'll see if I can use it in the future also :-)! For the "Fit" function: I'm giving it the datasets from x1,x2,x3.. y1,y2,y3.. However, it seems that the size of each array needs to be identical otherwise I get the classic "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (25,) (46,) ". Do the shapes need to be identical for the fitting? Thanks.

Comment: Glad you like it! If I did my job correctly, they shouldn't have to be the same size. Are you sure your `x_i`, `y_i` and `sigma_y_i` have the same shape? Within each component of the model they have to have the same shape. If they are, can you try calling the model manually like this: `fit.model([your data here], a=-0.6, b=5, c_1=12, etc.)`. This should evaluate each component of the model individually, and this call should work. http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#named-models

Comment: I'm using the input:

Comment: This is the input:

'fit = Fit(model_dict, x_1=x[0], x_2=x[1],x_3=x[2], x_4=x[3],x_5=x[4], x_6=x[5], y_1=y[0], y_2=y[1], y_3=y[2], y_4=y[3], y_5=y[4], y_6=y[5],
sigma_y_1=yerr[0], sigma_y_2=yerr[1],sigma_y_3=yerr[2],sigma_y_4=yerr[3],sigma_y_5=yerr[4],sigma_y_6=yerr[5])
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(fit_result)'

such that 'x[i],y[i],yerr[i]' are all the same shape.

Comment: After playing around with it some more, I retract my statement. They have to be of the same length in the current version of `symfit`. So I implemented a quick workaround for you and will change my answer to give it to you. After cleaning up and generalizing I will put this in the new version of `symfit` as well. Thank you for pointing this out and helping me improve this package :).

Comment: You gave me some idea's to go forward, and I will also try to use your code to make it work as mine is very rough! Glad I could help :)! and thank you for continuously responding to my questions.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to change the function to be fitted so that each data set has its own "a" and "b" parameter with a common "c", similar to this crude code snippet:

```
def func(x,a1,b1,a2,b2,a3,b3,a4,b4,a5,b5,a6,b6, c):
    if x in data_set_1:
        return (a1*(x**2)+b1*x+c)
    if x in data_set_2:
        return (a2*(x**2)+b2*x+c)
    if x in data_set_3:
        return (a3*(x**2)+b3*x+c)
    if x in data_set_4:
        return (a4*(x**2)+b4*x+c)
    if x in data_set_5:
        return (a5*(x**2)+b5*x+c)
    if x in data_set_6:
        return (a6*(x**2)+b6*x+c)
    raise Exception('Data outside fitting range') # just in case
```

Comment: You got the shared and individual parameters backwards.